# Does a program use the same cpu registers everytime it is run?

Tags: cpu-registers, instruction-set

When a program is run it uses the various registers eax, ebx etc. to store and move data.

Does a program use the same registers every time it is run?

Can the registers it does or does not use be found?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it is compiled to machine code, it will use the same registers all the time. If it is interpreted or compiled to byte code (think Java or C#) it can use different registers on each run.

Comment: Not disputing the answer per se, but interested in knowing why byte-code would not (in almost all cases) deterministically compile down to the same machine code each time (thus reusing the same registers)?

Comment: @ChristopheD it might be the same, but if the code is just-in-time compiled and the VM uses any tricks like hotspot optimization or dynamic specialization, then the generated code could easily depend on the data encountered by the program.